# Uniform convergence of geometric series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^n x^n e^{-nx}$

Tags: analysis, uniform-convergence

I am trying to prove that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^n x^n e^{-nx} $ converges uniformly on $[0,a]\bigcup[b,\infty)$ where $a<1, b>1$ is it enough to prove uniform convergence on the two intervals separately? Can this be done with the Weierstrass M test ?

Comment: Yes you can use Weierstrass. Note that your series is just a geometrical series: $\sum w^n$ where $w = e\cdot x \cdot e^{-x}$. Try to study how $w$ changes with $x$ (find the maximum).

Comment: So is the argument simply that the maximum of $w$ is 1 at $x=1$. as $x=1$ is not in the interval we can say $w \lt 1$ for all $x \in I $ and so the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} w^n$ converges uniformly on the interval?

Comment: Yes, but you need the slightly stronger statement $|w| \leq r < 1$ for all $x\in I$ to apply Weierstrass (which is the case as the maximum of $w$ over all $x$ is either at $a$ or at $b$).

Comment: btw are you sure the interval is $[0,a] \cup [0,b]$ ? I assumed it was $[0,a] \cup [b,\infty)$. If it's the former then $1$ is in the interval and you no longer have uniform convergence.

Comment: yes its $[b,\infty)$ changed above. thanks! think Ive got it.